# ¿Cómo hacer un backup de la parte fisica solamente de mi Base datos?

Tags: sql, sql-server

necesito hacer un backup pero solamente de la parte física de una base de datos, estoy usando sql server 2000, me refiero a que, si se puede hacer un backup de los archivos .log y .mdf por separado. Desde ya muchas gracias y 
saludos.

Comment: Copiando y pegando? En linux las bds de mysql están en `/var/lib/mysql`, con una carpeta por bd.

Comment: ¿qué otra parte tiene una base de datos, que no sea la _parte física_?

Comment: @jachguate, la logica, saludos.

Comment: @Peregring-lk gracias por tu aporte, estoy en windows, pero linux es una tarea pendiente en mi lista, gracias bro, muchas gracias y saludos.

Comment: @Rober, Al mover .log y .mdf no solo mueves _datos_, sino también _stored procedures, stored functions_, etc. Si pregunto es porque en la terminología estándar, no se hace separación de una _parte física_ (como tu le llamas), con respecto de otra parte de la base de datos. Si que existe algunos conceptos, como el _phisical storage_ de algunos motores. Como dije en otra pregunta que hiciste, estás preguntando sobre Y, cuando debes preguntar sobre X, pero creo que no seguiste los vínculos que te di.

Answer (score 0):

Si. Es posible, puedes copiar los archivos .mdf y despues para hacer la restauracion, adjuntarlos. Esto es llamado "Cold Backup".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que buen aporte @Jorge González , estoy en sql server 2000, pero veo que ya es hora de mudar me parece, desde ya muchas gracias y saludos.